# Four columns based on four keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a table first based on information that consists of 5 numbers and a year (+B sometimes):

```
SELECT  number5,    
YEAR(MyDate) AS [year], 
            concat(a.[number5],'-',YEAR(MyDate)) AS [A1],  
            concat(a.[number5],'-',YEAR(MyDate)-1) AS [A1-1],
            concat(a.[number5], '-',YEAR([MyDate]),'B') AS [B1],
            concat(a.[number5],'-',YEAR(MyDate)-1,'B') AS [B1-1]

 INTO #temp
 FROM aTable
```

So you would get:

```
number5 year   A1          A1-1         B1           B1-1
12345   2001   12345-2001  12345-2000   12345-2001B  12345-2000B   
23456   2002   23456-2002  23456-2001   23456-2002B  23456-2001B
34569   2003   34569-2003  34569-2002   34569-2003B  34569-2002B
45678   2004   45678-2004  45678-2003   45678-2004B  45678-2003B
```

Then I join this table with other information:

```
FileName        Value    Brand
12345-2001      10000    Apple
23456-2002      30409    Microsoft
34569-2003      09283    Microsoft
12345-2001B     20398    Apple
45678-2003B     20384    Apple

SELECT * FROM OtherTable AS a LEFT JOIN #temp AS b ON
b.A1 = a.Filename
```

However, this gives values for one row and NULL values for another row. How can I program it in a way that it understands that if I join the FileName with one of the columns of A1, A1-1,B1 and B1-1, that it also puts the information in new columns. So:

```
Numb5   year   A1            A1-1           B1          B1-1        FileN. Value     Brand    FileN. Value Brand     FileN.        Value  Brand.
12345   2001   12345-2001  12345-2000   12345-2001B  12345-2000B 12345-2001 10000    Apple                        12345-2001B     20398    Apple
```

I already tried a self join (but maybe wrongly):

```
WITH RLT AS (
SELECT *, Row_number() over (PARTITION BY [FileName] ORDER BY [year] Desc) RN FROM OtherTable)
```

So what I want is that it looks up the Value in row 1 A1 which is: 12345-2001 and returns the values of:
FileName Value Brand

And then looks up the second value in the same row which is: 12345-2000 and return the values of:
FileName Value Brand.

However, I want them to be next to each other, so:

```
A1   A1-1 B1  B1-1  FileName (A1)  Value (A1)  Brand (A1)  FileName (A1-1) Value (A1-1) Brand (A1-1)  FileName (B1) Value (B1) Brand (B1) FileName (B1-1) Value (B1-1) Brand (B1-1).
```

Comment: I don't get it.  `#temp` doesn't have a column called `FileName`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's not very clear but I think that is in another table that isn't shown (Othertable)

Comment: @JacobH . . . `Othertable` has the alias `a`.  The `on` clause already uses a column from that table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah you're right. This makes no sense at all. That's probably the issue in the query is that the table is joined to itself with a LEFT JOIN on that column. Hence the "get values for one row and nulls for another row" problem.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant b.A1 = a.FileName of course..

Comment: So the problem is that while the query gives you the rows for 12345-2001, 23456-2002, and 34569-2003 alright, the #temp columns for the other two rows are empty? You want FileName to match A1 or A1-1 or B1 or B1-1 instead of only A1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound like you're saying, when you query `OtherTable LEFT JOIN #temp`, some `OtherTable` records do not find a matching `#temp` record, hence `NULL` cells show up next to the `OtherTable` record, am I right?

Based on this understanding, the last data sample you provided and the rest of the question, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    T.number5, T.year, T.[A1], T.[A1-1], T.[B1], T.[B1-1]
  , OT1.FileName, OT1.Value, OT1.Brand
  , OT2.FileName, OT2.Value, OT2.Brand
  , OT3.FileName, OT3.Value, OT3.Brand
  , OT4.FileName, OT4.Value, OT4.Brand
FROM #temp AS T
LEFT JOIN OtherTable AS OT1 ON OT1.FileName = T.[A1]
LEFT JOIN OtherTable AS OT2 ON OT2.FileName = T.[A1-1]
LEFT JOIN OtherTable AS OT3 ON OT3.FileName = T.[B1]
LEFT JOIN OtherTable AS OT4 ON OT4.FileName = T.[B1-1]
```

Comment: No there are NULL values that is okay. However, I would like to match the data on just 1 row, instead of more than 1 row. So I want that the query understands that the match that is made should be on all four, and it should return columns with values on all four keys

Comment: This looks close to me, and KUDOS for for a close attempt.  I had alot of trouble understanding the question until I read this.  @Probs have you tried this?  It seems to me 1 row would be provided for 12345-2001 and it's other information, and then other information for A1-1,B1,B1-1 would also be provided.

Comment: I think it works, but because the column names are the same I cannot save it as a new table (SELECT * INTO..). Any tips and tricks for that so that I can test it in an Excel file or in Python?

Comment: @Probs, did you the names, although you should've done them yourself since: (1) it's specific to your tables, people sometimes don't post actual table/column names here, and (2) it's too straightforward, no mystery in doing it >.>

Comment: Thank you very much KtX2SkD. I asked it because I have a looot more columns than I posted here which are endlessly repeated now. I know this method you posted, but I thought maybe there is a smarter (and faster) way.. =D

Comment: @Probs, I get it now... well, combining some Mircosoft Excel formulas with some `EXEC sp_help` or `sys.objects JOIN sys.columns` usually fulfills my needs for mass-column-management in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try :) Very nice of you to help me out!